# Can't create connection to Database inside of docker container, host name won't translate

Tags: r, postgresql, docker, odbc, dbi

I created an instance of RStudio running inside of a docker container. When working inside of the container, I get the following error when trying to connect to Postgres database: "Error: could not translate host name "ABC-123" to address: Name or service not known".

On my local machine, I execute this step very easily like this:

```
# Load Libraries
# renv::init()
library(tidyverse)
library(glue)
library(dbplyr)
library(odbc)
library(DBI)
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(sendmailR)
library(paws)
library(config)
library(fs)
# renv::snapshot()


con <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(), 
                 dbname   = EDP_db, 
                 host     = EDP_host_db, 
                 port     = EDP_db_port, 
                 user     = EDP_db_user, 
                 password = EDP_db_password)
```

However, inside of the container I get the above mentioned error.

Here is the code for my dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/tidyverse:latest

# environment variables
ENV RENV_CONFIG_REPOS_OVERRIDE https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/latest


# Install dependency libraries
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
  build-essential \
  libxml2-dev \
  libcurl4-openssl-dev \
  libicu-dev \
  libsodium-dev \
  libssl-dev \
  libmagick++-dev \
  libudunits2-dev \
  libgdal-dev \
  libgeos-dev \
  libproj-dev \
  lbzip2 \
  libpq-dev \
  make \
  && apt-get clean
  
# expose port on Docker container (Ports that docker opens up) & set working directory
EXPOSE 8787
EXPOSE 5610 # (Port of DB)
EXPOSE 1440
RUN mkdir -p /app
RUN chmod -R 755 /app 
WORKDIR /app/
 

# install R-packages into Docker container
COPY renv.lock renv.lock 
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('renv', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN Rscript -e "renv::restore()"


# copy necessary files and data into app folder
COPY daily_leads.R /app/daily_leads.R
COPY config.yml /app/config.yml
COPY qk526-rpms-rp-daily-leads.Rproj /app/qk526-rpms-rp-daily-leads-app.Rproj
```

Lastly, here is the commands that I am using to build the docker image:

```
docker build -t daily_leads_app:1.0 --build-arg HTTP_PROXY="http://LCPzen.fpl.com:10262" --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY="http://LCPzen.fpl.com:10262" .

docker run --rm -d -p 8787:8787 daily_leads_app:1.0
```

This is a project for my job, hence the reason for the proxy. I am not sure what type of network that the docker host is configured to use, nor how to configure said network. I have been doing my best to google possible solutions, and the suggestions that seem to be most applicable recommend using a docker compose yaml file to initiate an instance of a postgres database and then make sure the name of the host is the name of the database service you've chosen in docker-compose.yml. However, the database that I am connecting to is a private company database, not something that I can save to my local machine. (Oh, and the error message mentioned above is the copy and pasted error message recieved in the Rstudio console.)

Comment: I think what may be more important here (but not shown) is how you are instantiating the docker image, and what kind of networking is the docker host configured to use here. And can you [edit] your question to add the R code and the literal error message? I can't find "translate" in the repos for `DBI` or `RPostgres`.

Comment: Voting to close as needing details and no response. Good luck!